# How can i run wsl on windows from gitlab CI?

Tags: windows, gitlab, gitlab-ci, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using Windows 10 Pro and have installed gitlab runner with pwsh shell.
I'm trying to start wsl, but Gitlab returns an empty output and an error code.
[gitlab ci error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLhOz.png)
My .gitlab-ci.yml

```
Build WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04:
  stage: Build
  tags:
    - windows
  script:
   - Write-Output "hello"
   - dir C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe 
   - Get-Service WslService
   - wsl.exe --help
```

I'm trying to enable gitlab runner debug log, and what do I see:

```
Checking for jobs... received                       job=42465 repo_url=https://gitlab.clive.tk/kubes/wsl2.git runner=rgsws7VJz
Processing chain                                    chain-leaf=[0xc000956b00 0xc000957080] context=certificate-chain-build resolve-full-chain=true
Certificate doesn't provide parent URL: exiting the loop  Issuer=Certificate Authority IssuerCertURL=[] Serial=1 Subject=Certificate Authority context=certificate-chain-build
Failed to requeue the runner                        builds=1 runner=rgsws7VJz
Running with gitlab-runner 16.1.0 (b72e108d)        job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
  on clivetk rgsws7VJz, system ID: s_f4336df4ca45   job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
Preparing the "shell" executor          job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
Shell configuration: command: pwsh
arguments:
- -NoProfile
- -NoLogo
- -InputFormat
- text
- -OutputFormat
- text
- -NonInteractive
- -ExecutionPolicy
- Bypass
- -EncodedCommand
- JABPAHUAdABwAHUAdABFAG4AYwBvAGQAaQBuAGcAIAA9ACAAWwBjAG8AbgBzAG8AbABlAF0AOgA6AEkAbgBwAHUAdABFAG4AYwBvAGQAaQBuAGcAIAA9ACAAWwBjAG8AbgBzAG8AbABlAF0AOgA6AE8AdQB0AHAAdQB0AEUAbgBjAG8AZABpAG4AZwAgAD0AIABOAGUAdwAtAE8AYgBqAGUAYwB0ACAAUwB5AHMAdABlAG0ALgBUAGUAeAB0AC4AVQBUAEYAOABFAG4AYwBvAGQAaQBuAGcADQAKAHAAdwBzAGgAIAAtAEMAbwBtAG0AYQBuAGQAIAAtAA0ACgA=
cmdline: pwsh -NoProfile -NoLogo -InputFormat text -OutputFormat text -NonInteractive
  -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -EncodedCommand JABPAHUAdABwAHUAdABFAG4AYwBvAGQAaQBuAGcAIAA9ACAAWwBjAG8AbgBzAG8AbABlAF0AOgA6AEkAbgBwAHUAdABFAG4AYwBvAGQAaQBuAGcAIAA9ACAAWwBjAG8AbgBzAG8AbABlAF0AOgA6AE8AdQB0AHAAdQB0AEUAbgBjAG8AZABpAG4AZwAgAD0AIABOAGUAdwAtAE8AYgBqAGUAYwB0ACAAUwB5AHMAdABlAG0ALgBUAGUAeAB0AC4AVQBUAEYAOABFAG4AYwBvAGQAaQBuAGcADQAKAHAAdwBzAGgAIAAtAEMAbwBtAG0AYQBuAGQAIAAtAA0ACgA=
dockercommand:
- pwsh
- -NoProfile
- -NoLogo
- -InputFormat
- text
- -OutputFormat
- text
- -NonInteractive
- -ExecutionPolicy
- Bypass
- -EncodedCommand
- JABPAHUAdABwAHUAdABFAG4AYwBvAGQAaQBuAGcAIAA9ACAAWwBjAG8AbgBzAG8AbABlAF0AOgA6AEkAbgBwAHUAdABFAG4AYwBvAGQAaQBuAGcAIAA9ACAAWwBjAG8AbgBzAG8AbABlAF0AOgA6AE8AdQB0AHAAdQB0AEUAbgBjAG8AZABpAG4AZwAgAD0AIABOAGUAdwAtAE8AYgBqAGUAYwB0ACAAUwB5AHMAdABlAG0ALgBUAGUAeAB0AC4AVQBUAEYAOABFAG4AYwBvAGQAaQBuAGcADQAKAHAAdwBzAGgAIAAtAEMAbwBtAG0AYQBuAGQAIAAtAA0ACgA=
passfile: false
extension: ps1
  job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
Using Shell (pwsh) executor...                      job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
Waiting for signals...                              job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
No referees configured                              job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
Executing build stage                               build_stage=prepare_script job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
Preparing environment                   job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
Using new shell command execution                   job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
Executing build stage                               build_stage=get_sources job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
Getting source from Git repository      job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
Using new shell command execution                   job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
Feeding runners to channel                          builds=1
Feeding runner to channel                           builds=1 runner=rgsws7VJz
Appending trace to coordinator...ok                 code=202 job=42465 job-log=0-544 job-status=running runner=rgsws7VJz sent-log=0-543 status=202 Accepted update-interval=1m0s
Executing build stage                               build_stage=restore_cache job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
Skipping stage (nothing to do)                      build_stage=restore_cache job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
Executing build stage                               build_stage=download_artifacts job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
Skipping stage (nothing to do)                      build_stage=download_artifacts job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
Executing build stage                               build_stage=step_script job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script  job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
Using new shell command execution                   job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
Executing build stage                               build_stage=after_script job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
Skipping stage (nothing to do)                      build_stage=after_script job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
Executing build stage                               build_stage=archive_cache_on_failure job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
Skipping stage (nothing to do)                      build_stage=archive_cache_on_failure job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
Executing build stage                               build_stage=upload_artifacts_on_failure job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
Skipping stage (nothing to do)                      build_stage=upload_artifacts_on_failure job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
Skipping referees execution                         job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
Executing build stage                               build_stage=cleanup_file_variables job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables  job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
Using new shell command execution                   job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
WARNING: Job failed: exit status 1
                 duration_s=20.3925953 job=42465 project=248 runner=rgsws7VJz
Appending trace to coordinator...ok                 code=202 job=42465 job-log=0-14895 job-status=running runner=rgsws7VJz sent-log=544-14894 status=202 Accepted update-interval=1m0s
```

But if i run wsl from powershell windows - it starts successfully.
How can i run wsl with gitlab ci?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like WSL is not properly configured or enabled on the GitLab runner machine. A few things to check:

- Make sure WSL is installed and enabled. Run wsl --list in PowerShell
  to verify it is working.
- The GitLab runner may not have the necessary permissions to run WSL.
  Make sure the service account running the runner is added to the
  "Windows Subsystem for Linux Users" group.
- WSL requires virtualization support. Verify virtualization is enabled
  in the BIOS.
- Try running the build on the host directly rather than through
  Docker, since Docker may not have full access to WSL:

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - windows 
  script:
    - pwsh -c "wsl --help"
```

- Explicitly start the WSL service before trying to use it:

```yaml
build:
  script:
    - Start-Service WslService
    - wsl --help
```

- Check the runner logs for any errors related to WSL to help
  troubleshoot further.

The key is making sure WSL is properly set up on the GitLab runner host, and that the runner has sufficient permissions to use it.